# Inner scope changing value of variable defined in outer scope

Tags: python, global-variables

I did a coding practice about symmetric square.

Here is the instruction:
A list is symmetric if the first row is the same as the first column,
the second row is the same as the second column and so on. Write a
procedure, symmetric, which takes a list as input, and returns the
boolean True if the list is symmetric and False if it is not.

the following is the test case written by Udacity

```
print symmetric([[1, 2, 3],
           [2, 3, 4],
            [3, 4, 1]])  
->True

print symmetric([["cat", "dog", "fish"],
            ["dog", "dog", "fish"],
            ["fish", "fish", "cat"]])
-> True

print symmetric([["cat", "dog", "fish"],
           ["dog", "dog", "dog"],
           ["fish","fish","cat"]])
-> False
```

so here is my code:

```
def symmetric(list1):
  i=0
  j=0
  if list1 == []:
    return True
  if len(list1) != len(list1[0]):
    return False
  while i<len(list1):
    while j<len(list1):
        if list1[i][j] !=list1[j][i]:
            return False
        j=j+1
    i=i+1
  return True
```

i think it would work but when udacity runs the test case,it says this doesn't pass the test case of  [['algebra', 'combinatorics', 'graphs'], ['combinatorics', 'topology', 'sets'], ['graphs', 'topology', 'sets']]

When i changed the location of "j=0"  into the first while loop, it actually passed the test case

```
def symmetric(list1):
  i=0
  if list1 == []:
    return True
  if len(list1) != len(list1[0]):
    return False
  while i<len(list1):
    j=0
    while j<len(list1):
        if list1[i][j] !=list1[j][i]:
            return False

        j=j+1
    i=i+1
  return True
```

i used to write code in java before and I don't think in java it makes a big difference. However,in python case, is this because of local variable vs. global variable? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`j` is defined outside the scope of the while loop, so as you increment `j` in the loop, you are incrementing the variable defined in the outer scope.

For what it's worth, this is a slightly more terse way to do that:

```
def symmetric(inval):
    return map(tuple, inval) == zip(*inval)
```

And this is a slightly more pythonic way of writing your approach

```
def symmetric(list1):
    i=0
    if not list1:
        return True
    if not set(map(len, list1)) == set([len(list1)]):
        return False

    for i in range(0, len(list1)):
        for j in range(0, len(list1)):
            if list1[i][j] !=list1[j][i]:
                return False
    return True
```

It also tests that all sublists are the same length, and that that length is the same as the top level list.